# mysql count total last week from timestamp

Tags: mysql

```
     id  date
    1  1288006344
    2  1288010391
    3  1288010752
    4  1288011379
    5  1288013258
    6  1288014043
    7  1288014555
    8  1288015611
    9  1288019119
    10  1288020490
    11  1288023483
    12  1288029300
    13  1288031668
    14  1288032090
```

How to count total last 7 days?

Thank you !

Comment: Please explain your question.

Comment: Why aren't you storing your timestamps in a `TIMESTAMP` column?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

something like this should do the trick:

```
SELECT count(*) FROM your_table_name 
WHERE 
  date_sub(curdate(), INTERVAL 7 DAY) <= date;
```

That will select dates that are *after* 7-days ago.  If you want to exclude any dates that are in the future, you'll have to add a clause for that:

```
SELECT count(*) FROM your_table_name 
WHERE 
  date_sub(curdate(), INTERVAL 7 DAY) <= date
  AND NOW() >= date;
```

more info on the various mysql date functions is available at [the mysql documentation site](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html).

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT SUM(mycolumn) AS TOTAL
  FROM mytable
 WHERE FROM_UNIXTIME(mybigint_column_containing_unixtimestamps) >= 
       DATE_SUB(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,INTERVAL 7 DAY)
```